# Resize constraint with keyboard animation

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I'm trying to animate my `UIStackView` which contains a login form whenever the keyboard appears. I want to do it only by adjusting constraints from my storyboard file.

This is my layout:

[image: Layout]

My code resizes the bottom constraint depending on the size of the keyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)

    keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint.isActive = false
}

func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint.isActive = true
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

        if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
            self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = 0.0
        } else {
            self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = (endFrame?.size.height)! + 20
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       delay: TimeInterval(0),
                       options: animationCurve,
                       animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                       completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The result is that it only shrinks the size of the UIStackView because the top constraint wont allow it to move upwards, example:

[image: Result]

This has to do with the top constraint of my stackview. Deleting this constraint solves the problem but on smaller resolutions the form might overlap with the `UIImageView`. Is there a way to update this constraint to reflect the changes of the bottom constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up outlets to both the top and bottom constraints and change them both. I've done that a number of times.

I'm not totally clear on your constraint layout, but I'm guessing that you want to **add** to the bottom layout's constraint and **subtract** from the top layout constraint.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Does that mean I need a bottom outlet constraint and a top outlet constraint? Lets say if the bottom gets +20 the top should get -20? This would work without getting constraints conflicts?

Comment: And then you'd reverse the change when you hide the keyboard (subtract 20 from the bottom and add 20 to the top.)

Comment: I did the following:

Create 3 Constraint outlets: 
1 Bottom constraint between UIStackView and bottom layout Guide
1 top constraint between UIStackView and UIImageView
1 top constraint between UIImageView and top layout guide

In code:

1: Calculate how much was added to the bottom layout constraint.
2: Divide the addition / 2 
3: Substract each halve over the 2 top constraints.

However my stackview gets stretched and I receive the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." message.

Comment: If that didn't make any sense, here are the before and after keyboard event pictures:

[![before.jpg](https://s12.postimg.org/akeixgzgd/before.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/fvtfi6lix/)

[![after.png](https://s17.postimg.org/rn9jb083z/after.png)](https://postimg.org/image/mom0wh4az/)

Comment: You should only need 2 to change 2 constraints. If you want the stack view **and** the image view to move, leave the constraint between them alone and adjust the bottom-most and top-most constraints.

Comment: Calculating how much is added at the bottom and substracting it from the top causes the form to stretch in size for some weird reason.

Comment: What kind of constraint is on the top, and what view(s) does it connect to?

Comment: The constraint is between the stackview and the imageView is a constraint with the priority of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Lower the priority of that constraint (the one from the image view to the stack view) to 200. A priority of 200 is lower than the default content compression priorities, so autolayout will break it before squishing other views.

Comment: I tried that but that results in [![Simulator Screen Shot 1 Dec 2016, 23.57.14.png](https://s11.postimg.org/bbzs3lunn/Simulator_Screen_Shot_1_Dec_2016_23_57_14.png)](https://postimg.org/image/9wy7evtkf/)

The top constraint is missing so it's possible to overlap on smaller resolutions